# How may I solve this system of 5 equations using ODE45 (algebraic equations involved)?

Tags: matlab, ode, ode45

I am a seasoned **Matlab** programmer, yet I don't know how to solve this (seemingly) simple problem. I have a system of 5 equations and 5 unknowns:

[image: system]

I know how to solve ODEs using ode45 when there are *no algebraic equations involved*. In the system above, **V** (velocity) and **C** (acceleration) are both **constant and known.** *C is the spacecraft transverse acceleration.*

This problem should be solved as follows:

1. At t=0, we know Theta(0), x(0) and y(0). Remember that V and C are both constant and known.
2. Given Theta(0) and C/V, we get Theta(t1) integrating the 4th equation. With this new value of Theta, we should be able to compute the new Vx(t1) and Vy(t1), which will give us the new values for x(t1) and y(t2).
3. Repeat

It's important to solve the problem using Matlab's ODE45, because it will eventually get pretty difficult to solve when I add wind, varying gravity and densities, the spacecraft mass and geometry (and inertias and so on!). So I will get a system of dozens of equations which will all be coupled. If I get to know how to solve this simple problem in Matlab, I will understand how to solve more complex ones in the future.

I've scavenged the internet in order to find some help, but it was in vain. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the corrected system you only have 3 state variables to integrate

```
function dotu = f(t,u)
    theta = y(1); 
    dotu = [ C/V, -V*cos(theta), V*sin(theta) ];
end
```

and this you can then directly insert into the solver

```
[ T,U ] = ode45(f, [t0, tf], [ theta0, x0, y0])
```

using the appropriate values for the initial condition and the integration end.

Comment: Thank you for all your time @LutzL, now I understand the problem!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your system is underdetermined in the sense that y_1 is not constrained by your equations other than it has to be positive. As for the rest of the system, it actually decouples. Here's how I would do it:

1) The first equation implies that y_1 is positive. With that in mind, if you substitute y_2 and y_3 in the first equation you obtain the identity y_1=y_1. So that this point y_1 can be any function of time, subject only to the constraint that at t=0 it satisfies the initial condition. In the following, I will assume it to be a constant in time.

2) With that stipulation, C/y_1 is an arbitrary constant, let's call it B, from which it follows that y_4= Bt + y0_4, y0_4 being the integration constant.

3) Substitute y_2 into the 5th equation and y_3 into the 6th. Now you have two ODEs with a time dependent r.h.s. The equations are simple enough that they can solved analytically. For example, the last equation gives y_6=-y_1/B cos(Bt+y0_4)+y0_6.

More generally, suppose that you had a problem that was not underconstrained. Then, you can always differentiate in time the algebraic equations and obtained a coupled system of ODE.

As a last comment, I would say that, before rushing to Matlab (or Python, or R, or C++,...) it is always a good thing to work on the problem with paper and pencil to see if it can be simplified, or, as is the case above, it can be solved.

Comment: Why would you assume y_1 to be a constant?

Comment: y_1 is not a constant. Actually y_1 is a distance, which can be obtained from y_2 and y_3 which are the horizontal and vertical distances, respectively

Comment: I assumed y_1 to be constant for simplicity. In reality, it can be any function of time. The fact is, the mathematical problem as stated by the OP (plus initial conditions), does not have a unique solution (numeric or otherwise). Only when y_1(t) is given, the last 3 equations, with y_2 and y_3 obtained from the second and third equation, can be solved to give a unique solution, once the initial conditions are given. Moreover, the solution for y_4 does not depend on y_5 and y_6, so it can be obtained first. It can be substituted in the equation for y_5 and y_6 which can be solved by quadrature

Comment: I will rename variables and see if it makes more sense.

Comment: I renamed variables. V(t) is the total velocity, whereas Vx and Vy are the horizontal and vertical components, respectively. Theta is the angle that V makes with the horizontal (I assumed V is pointing to negative-x initially). "x" and "y" are the horizontal and vertical distances. I have initial conditions: V(0)=100; Theta(0)=20deg; x(0)=0; y(0)=10000. Please, help me solve this problem with matlab! I need to calculate V(t), x(t), y(y), theta(t), Vx(t) and Vy(t)

Comment: @JoseLopezGarcia : What physical situation is that supposed to model? The remark by user3646557 remains true, if `V(t)` is given then the other functions follow.

Comment: @LutzL It tries to model the movement of a mass-less spacecraft in the XY plane, given the initial conditions of my previous comment. Does this make sense? NOTE: The equation for d(Theta)/dt is a given guidance law.

Comment: @JoseLopezGarcia : Then there is no inertia, force or friction? What is the physical principle that `V(t)*theta'(t)=C` is modeling?

Comment: @LutzL Exactly, no dynamics in the problem. The equation `V(t)*theta=C` comes from the Proportional Navigation Guidance Law: `C` is the spacecraft transverse acceleration  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_navigation)

Comment: In my previous comment I meant `V(t)*theta'(t)=C`

Comment: @JoseLopezGarcia I do not see the connection to your equations. Could you add more on how you derived these equations?

Comment: It would be a bit long to derive these equations here. What if I asked you to solve the system using Matlab? You know the equations, you know the initial conditions. How should I proceed? That's all I need! (PD: The equations are derived in the book "Tactical and Strategical Missile Guidance" by Paul Zarchan, Chapter 2)

Comment: @JoseLopezGarcia The first sentence of the answer still remains true, the system is under-determined, `V(t)` can be freely chosen. There is no way to implement the system as given. The question for derivation steps is because of the suspicion that at some point you removed a non-trivial condition on the system.

Comment: The problem is actually pretty simple: the spacecraft is moving initially at speed V(0) with an angle of Theta(0). As time increases, Theta changes so that `theta'=C/V`. Given the new value of Theta, the velocity V will have changed to a new value. And the process repeats: given this new value of V, Theta will get yet another value, and so on.

Comment: @LutzL Oh, I made a huge mistake. Indeed, V is a constant, which changes the whole problem. Let me rephrase it in the original question.

Comment: @user3646557 Huh, that was a great instinct my friend! Turned out you were right after all!